# IOS/Autolayout possible for just top view without setting for subviews?

Tags: ios, view, autolayout

I have prototyped an app without using auto layout relying primarily on hard coded dimensions using the size inspector optimized for an iPhone SE (or 5).

The main reason I did this is lack of knowledge of auto layout and the difficulty of redoing constraints after making this or that change.

The problem I now face is that the app screens sized to the SE are not large enough to fill the space of an iPhone 6 or especially 7 plus.  The screens leave a border of black of varying sizes at top and bottom depending on the difference between the SE and the other target.

The elements of each screen are generally contained in one view per view controller.

I was wondering if there is any way to just set a few constraints to expand the master view to adjust to the phone screen size without needing constraints for every single element within the view?

If not, I will just bite the bullet and begin putting in dozens of constraints but wondering if there is a minimalist approach possible.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way called UIViewAutoresizing, but it strictly depends on layout.
 Reference: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622559-autoresizingmask

Comment: Is it now the case that you have to use Autolayout?  Autoresizing seems like it is the older approach.

Comment: It's hard to recommend something specific without knowing details. I would go with Autolayout.

Comment: What I meant was can you just set constraints for the outermost view to get it to fill up screen without adding constraints for every element (subview)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you decided to stick with the autolayout...

Imagine you have **many UI elements** on the scene (and let`s say some inside the others) and at first you have not set any constraints at all.

At the very beginning you **are not satisfied with all/or almost all elements** autolayout. And this is since you did set nothing (no constraints/autoresizing masks etc.) to any of them at all. So the reaction to the rotations/moves during the runtime/screen size changing etc. is almost **unpredictable** for **each of them** (let`s just call it “**reaction**”).

How it can be fixed? We know there`s a **solution** called “constraints".

The constraints set up the **relationship** between the **two** elements (not 3, 4 or … n - many) which's formula is
`UIView.attribute1 = multiplier * UIView2.attribute2 + constant B`.

Let's start from the 1st UI element (your SomeView - let`s call it View1) which is a child element to the Superview .
At the beginning you are not satisfied with its reaction. So you set the constraints up for that ONE specific element. You layout it on the scene.

Now you have new relationship

- `UIView1.attribute = UIViewNth.attributeN + B` . 
   
  //which is actually `UIView1.attribute1 = Superview.attribute2 + B`.

set up **between only the 2 elements**: superview and **ONE** (not many) specific element (your SomeView which we just called View1). 
//(you has the layout/constraints set for **ONE** specific element - View1 - which is “SomeView").

You implemented the solution for two of them (actually one, not taking into account the Superview, - for someView which is a child view for superView of the scene).
Now you **can predict the reaction** for SomeView respectively to the Superview.

**All of the rest** UIElement`s reaction is still **remained unpredictable**. All of the rest UI elements **is unrelated to each other** and any of them. **No layout** set for **any of them (the rest UI elements)**.

You have 1 working properly. Still not satisfied?

So let`s go further.

Now you set the constraints up for the 2nd **ONE** specific element. You layout it by making the relationship which is now between the 2nd one and Superview/or some other n-th UI element on your scene which is already sticked (related to somewhere) so while the 2nd one will be sticked to the n-th one they will not move off/crash down/etc together. 1st is sticked to the 2nd, second to the 3rd etc.

So now you have the **new relationship**

- `UIView2.attribute3  = Uiview1.attribute4 + A` (A is some value). 
  //or `UIView2.attribute3  = Superview.attribute4` + A (some value).

Now you can **predict the reaction** for the **2nd UI element**. It`s reaction **in accordance** with the **1st** element.

**Or with the Superview/or** with the **1st** element (which is already **sticked to the superview**). Up to you.

At this very moment you have in total

- `[Superview] - [View1]` relationship / you did layout 1 view / set constraints for the 1st (`[Superview] - [View1]`)
- `[View1] - [View2]` relationship / you did layout 2nd view / set constraints for the 2nd (`[View2] - [View1]`)

All of the rest **3...n** elements on the scene are still **unpredictable**. Let`s call it **k...n** where the **n is the last one**. Unsatisfied?

Now you set the layout for the **k-th** **element** like you did before. **k-1 UI elements** on your scene **remains unsatisfied**.

… And so on

Repeat **up to the n-th (last) UI element** on your scene.

---

**So answering your question**. No. There`s not a short (few - constraint approach) solution if you have many UI elements and want to make most of them react properly at the run time.